# Python: how to save text + element from the list to the txt file

Tags: python, list, text, txt

I'm learning Python and I'm trying to combine saving text + specific element from the list to a txt file.

I managed to get the text out and it looks like this:

Project name:
Main worker:
Project name:
Main worker:

and this is fine but I would like to add workers and projects that are in the lists to look like this:

Project name: Microsoft
Main tester: Michael Scott
Project name: Amazon
Main tester: Dwight Schrute

And I'm not sure how to add that, this is what I got so far:

```
class Worker:
    def __init__(self, name, lastname):
        self.name = name
        self.lastname = lastname

    def name_lastname(self):
        print(self.name, self.name)

class Project:
    def __init__(self, name, worker):
        self.name = name
        self.worker = worker

workers = []
projects = []

name1 = input("Enter the name: ")
lastname1 = input("Enter the last name: ")
workers.append(name1 + ' ' + lastname1)

name2 = input("Enter the name: ")
lastname2 = input("Enter the last name: ")
workers.append(name2 + ' ' + lastname2)

projectname1 = input("Enter the name of the project: ")
projectname2 = input("Enter the name of the project: ")
projects.append(projectname1)
projects.append(projectname2)

print(workers)
print(projects)

file = open("projects.txt","w")
file.write("Project name: \n")
file.write("Main worker: \n")
file.write("Project name: \n")
file.write("Main worker: \n")
file.close()
```

Comment: Warm welcome to SO! Please help us to help you. Can you simplify your code please and create a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is a bout to much. I assume you don't need so much lines to show us your problem. And also show us the input and the expected output of data. And please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Hey @buhtz thank you for your comment. I will make my questions more simple in the future and I will read the "how to ask a question" part.

Comment: It seems your `Worker` and `Project`class are absolutely useless for your example. Right? Please remove them in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, just writing the names and projects like you did with the headers (e.g. "Project name:") would be sufficient. For example:

```
file.write("Project name: \n")
file.write(projects[0] + "\n")
file.write("Main worker: \n")
file.write(workers[0] + "\n")
file.write("Project name: \n")
file.write(projects[1] + "\n")
file.write("Main worker: \n")
file.write(workers[1] + "\n")
file.close()
```

For lists, you can access the first element with a list[0], the second one with list[1] and so on. This is however a fairly manual approach and you could use a loop here to iterate over the list entries if you have more entries later on.

Answer (score 1):

I not sure about your input and output data but I hope I understand it correct. And because you are a Python learner I took the liberty to introduce some other Python techniques to make the solution more *Pythonic* and less error prone.

#### The full example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pathlib

# example data (assuming both lists with same length)
all_workers = ['John Doe', 'Jenny Boe']
all_projects = ['Project Alpha', 'Project Beta']

# file path
projects_file_path = pathlib.Path('projects.txt')

# open the file
with projects_file_path.open('w') as file_handle:
    # iterate over your lists side by side
    for worker, project in all_workers, all_projects:
        file_handle.write(f'Project name:\n{project}\n')
        file_handle.write(f'Main worker:\n{worker}\n')

# let's look what is in the file
with projects_file_path.open('r') as file_handle:
    print(file_handle.read())
```

The resulting `projects.txt` file look like this. Is this what you wanted?

```
Project name:
Jenny Boe
Main worker:
John Doe
Project name:
Project Beta
Main worker:
Project Alpha
```

#### Step-by-step explained

I removed the two classes from your example code because I couldn't see an advantage of them. I also removed the `input()` part and hard coded some sample data. Hope this is OK that way?

```
# example data (assuming both lists with same length)
all_workers = ['John Doe', 'Jenny Boe']
all_projects = ['Project Alpha', 'Project Beta']
```

To interact with files and the filesystem it is recommended to use Pythons [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html) package. The `with` block in the code make sure that the file is closed automatically when the block ends.

```
import pathlib
    
projects_file_path = pathlib.Path('projects.txt')

# open the file
with projects_file_path.open('w') as file_handle:
    # write...
```

I think the `for`-loop is self explaining. It's advantage is it prevents you from write repetitiv code.

I constructed the string written into the file with the `f`-string like this.

```
file_handle.write(f'Project name:\n{project}\n')
```

But you could also use the old way with `format()`.

```
file_handle.write('Project name:\n{}\n'.format(project))
```